# Use Python to Change csv Data Column Format

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas

I am using python pandas to read csv file. The csv file has a datetime column that has second precisions "9/1/2015  9:25:00 AM", but if I open in excel, it has only minute precisions "9/1/15 9:25". Moreover, when I use the pd.read_csv() function, it only shows up to minute precision. Is there any way that I could solve the problem using python? Thanks much in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it's a CSV problem, and not an Excel formatting problem?  By default, when Excel opens up a CSV, it will convert datetime values (rather annoyingly), and then format them with it's "Date" style which is MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM.  Try and change the format to "YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS.000"

Comment: Can you show how you csv actually looks (maybe first few lines of the csv) and then the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This is a time formatting problem/philosophy by Excel.  For some reason, Microsoft prefers to hide seconds and sub-seconds on user displays:   even MSDOS's `dir` command omitted seconds.

If I were you, I'd use Excel's `format` operation and set it to display seconds, then save the spreadsheet as CSV and see if it put anything in it to record the improved formatting.

If that doesn't work, you might explore creating a macro which does the formatting, or use one of the IPC to Excel to command it to do your bidding.

Comment: Excel won't save anything in a CSV file to indicate formatting.  It specifically tells you formatting will be lost saving it in that format.  Excel will potentially change the datetime value to something like "42293.0037430556", though, which is equally as annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Go in to "Format Cells" and enter `d/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss` as your custom formatting option

[image]

**Edit:** Not sure if I totally understand your question. Try this: create a text file with a single line "9/1/2015 9:25:00 AM", call it `test.csv`. Now do `df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None)`. If you print your column with `df[0]` you should see this:

```
In [35]: df[0]
Out[35]:
0    9/1/2015 9:25:00 AM
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

i.e. Pandas has just read the column as a string (object) and the seconds are right there.

If you want to convert to a timestamp, call `pd.to_datetime`

```
In [36]: pd.to_datetime(df[0])
Out[36]:
0   2015-09-01 09:25:00
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Again the seconds are still there. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Hi I have 90000+ files like this. It's not quite possible for me to use this functionality to manually change the formatting. Is there a way for me to call the pd.read_csv() function directly to display the time to seconds precision? Thanks.